# How to know when a tree view item is visible on screen?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-5.0

Can I somehow find if a tree view item is visible on screen?

I have some data to process which is heavy and if I do it for all items I got delay which I want to avoid.

I need **efficient** method to test if an item is in the visible portion of the tree.

Comment: By visible, do you mean its immediate parent is expanded? Or that it is actually rendered on the screen?

Comment: lets make it simple.. visible I mean - you actually can see this item on the screen (it is expanded and is not scrolled outside the visible area).. visible by human eye not by property Visibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
GeneralTransform gt = treeView.TransformToVisual(null);
var treeRect = gt.TransformBounds(new Rect(0, 0, treeView.ActualWidth, treeView.ActualHeight));
var visibleElements = VisualTreeHelper.FindElementsInHostCoordinates(treeRect, treeView);
var treeViewItemsVisibleOnScreen = visibleElements.OfType<TreeViewItem>();
```